Discrepancies in EPSG:3857 Spherical/Web Mercator World bounds
This Question Spherical Mercator - World bounds
is answered by this Answer,
which cites https://epsg.io/3857 with the following bounds:
xmin: -20037508.3427892,
ymin: -20037508.3427892,
xmax: 20037508.3427892,
ymax: 20037508.3427892

The website itself however lists these bounds:
xmin:-20037508.34
ymin:-20048966.1
xmax: 20037508.34
ymax: 20048966.1

Various other sources, such as Maptiler or libosmium, also show or use the bounds of the perfect square above.
My application using tiles created by planetiler also only works with the perfect square.
Why does this discrepancy exist, why does it appear to be barely or not at documented and should I just stick with the square or try and conform to https://epsg.io/3857?

These projected bounds
xmin: -20037508.3427892,
ymin: -20037508.3427892,
xmax: 20037508.3427892,
ymax: 20037508.3427892

match with the valid area of the Web Mercator projection in EPSG:4326 units
lon_min: -180.0
lat_min: -85.06
lon_max:  180.0
lat_max:  85.06

From Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Mercator_projection

The value 85.051129° is the latitude at which the full projected map
becomes a square, and is computed as...

However, the Earth continues beyond the limits until the poles and transformation formulas can compute y coordinates outside the valid area all the way to the poles.
Example with gdaltransform about the South Pole:
gdaltransform -s_srs epsg:4326 -t_srs epsg:3857
-180 -90
-20037508.3427892 -242528680.943743 0

Stick with the square area and latitudes between -85.06 - 85.06.
